# Identity comparison in golang?

Tags: go

I've been trying to build a set of structs that have a base struct as their foundation and variants built on top of that. I've found, however, that there doesn't seem to be a way for the struct to identify itself when the common code is in the base struct. How should I be doing this?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Base interface {
    IsMe(other Base) bool
}

type Block struct {
}

func (b *Block) IsMe(other Base) bool {
    return b == other
}

type Block2 struct {
    Block
}

func main() {
    b1 := &Block{}
    b2 := &Block2{}
    fmt.Printf("b1.IsMe(b1): %v\n", b1.IsMe(b1))
    fmt.Printf("b1.IsMe(b2): %v\n", b1.IsMe(b2))
    fmt.Printf("b2.IsMe(b1): %v\n", b2.IsMe(b1)) // Wrong result!
    fmt.Printf("b2.IsMe(b2): %v\n", b2.IsMe(b2)) // Wrong result!
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, I know I can add this:


    func (b *Block2) IsMe(other Base) bool {
        return b == other
    }

and I will then get the right result... however, I don't want to write the same boiler-plate code for every sub-struct.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35546054/golang-equivalent-of-is-operator-in-python

Comment: Thanks @IanAuld, but that link doesn't seem relevant to this particular problem. Note that there is an interface involved.

Comment: On a side note, it sounds like you're using, and thinking about, struct embedding as inheritence. You may be better off stepping back and thinking how you might solve the problem in a more Go idiomatic way. For example, the fact that your `IsMe` method takes an interface value, but you're not actually using any functionality defined by that interface, is a code smell.

Comment: I am indeed trying to do something akin to inheritance, as it can be quite useful in reducing boilerplate code. The example above was distilled down to its smallest case that would illustrate the problem, which is why it isn't actually doing anything useful, nor "using any functionality defined by that interface". The actual code does in fact use it quite extensively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Base interface {
    IsMe(other Base) bool
}

type Block struct {
    _ [1]byte // size of struct must be greater than zero
}

func (b *Block) IsMe(other Base) bool {
    x := reflect.ValueOf(b)
    y := reflect.ValueOf(other)
    return x.Pointer() == y.Pointer()
}

type Block2 struct {
    Block // "parent" needs to be first element
}

func main() {
    b1 := &Block{}
    b2 := &Block2{}
    fmt.Printf("b1.IsMe(b1): %v\n", b1.IsMe(b1))
    fmt.Printf("b1.IsMe(b2): %v\n", b1.IsMe(b2))
    fmt.Printf("b2.IsMe(b1): %v\n", b2.IsMe(b1))
    fmt.Printf("b2.IsMe(b2): %v\n", b2.IsMe(b2))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Dx0Ze3euFY

Comment: Thanks. This did the trick. I've eliminated the use of the unsafe package by changing the IsMe() content to this: return reflect.ValueOf(Base(b)).Pointer() == reflect.ValueOf(other).Pointer()

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to do it the fake inheritance way then you can certainly do it the way you did it but it really only works with `unsafe` or `reflect` because the language is not designed for what you want to do.

Your problem starts with where `x.IsMe` comes from when using embedding. When you write

```
type Block struct {}
func (b *Block) IsMe(other Base) bool { return b == other }
type Block2 struct { Block }
```

the method `IsMe` is actually associated and bound to `Block` instead of `Block2`. So calling `IsMe` on an instance of `Block2` is really only calling it on `Block`, in detail:

```
b2 := Block2{}
fmt.Println(b2.IsMe)       // 0x21560
fmt.Println(b2.Block.IsMe) // 0x21560
```

Both methods have the same address. This shows that even though `b2` has the method `IsMe`, that method is only propagated from `Block` to the outside of `Block2` and **not inherited**. This in turn means that you are always running effectively this code:

```
b1 := Block{}
b2 := Block2{}
b2_embedded_block := b2.Block
b2_embedded_block.IsMe(b2)
b2_embedded_block.IsMe(b1)
// ...
```

which obviously cannot work since you are comparing two completely different instances.

What you really should do is to use some function outside of your embedding chain to decide equality. Example ([On Play](https://play.golang.org/p/YsPjuQ5VBg)):

```
func IsEq(a,b Base) bool {
    return a == b
}
```

This actually compares the right instances.

Comment: That was what I wanted to do, but since it is the object itself that needs to compare itself against an interface stored elsewhere, I couldn't find a clean way to make it work without replicating code into every variation.

Comment: Your example is probably to abstract to highlight the underlying issue but the fact that you were unable to find a clean solution may indicate that your initial approach has flaws. The way you are doing it now (using `reflect`) is a workaround, not a solution.